# How should I edit this ROS wiki page?

Tags: ros, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have determined that the "Configuring a Linux Joystick" tutorial is outdated. See here:
http://ros.org/wiki/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick

There are two issues with this page. The first is that the "compiling" step is not needed, as far as I can tell, or perhaps it only applies to ROS build.

The second, is that the actual way to do it is like this:

> First run `rospack find joy`
>
> If you get an error, you can install joystick-drivers by running the following command:
>
> `sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-joystick-drivers`
>
> followed by
>
> `rosdep install joy`

(which I am borrowing from http://answers.ros.org/question/35945/rosdep-install-joy/ )

But the issue is, as you can see, the "fuerte" needs to be replaced with "groovy" if the user is using ROS groovy. Should there be an updated version with some of those buttons that let you select what buildsystem you are on, in addition to the buttons that let you select what version of ROS you are running? If so, how do you do that? I haven't been able to find it anywhere on the Wiki. Every time I see a page that has that sort of thing, the page is immutable so I can't see how it was done...

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61922/how-should-i-edit-this-ros-wiki-page?/) by [duffany1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4288/duffany1/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2013-05-01

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the 'More Actions -> raw view' dropdown in the right sidebar to view the wiki source for a particular page.

For stack and package pages, the version tags are auto-generated as part of the generic page header, so they aren't visible in the source.

You can create the version header with the `<Version()>` macro, and then use the `{{{#!wiki version <version>` header to designate particular sections as being specific to a particular version of ROS.

Note also that, for many of the instructions that include an install step, it should cover both installing from source and installing from debs, since ROS has a significant user base that installs from source.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2013-05-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [duffany1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4288/duffany1/) on 2013-05-03**:
When I do
`{{{!#wiki version groovy  {{{ $ sudo apt-get install ros-groovy-joystick-drivers }}} }}}`

The source code is not rendered. However, if I remove the source code brackets, the text is properly displayed. How do I nest source code brackets within the version section?